# Network Card Atheros problem Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: wireless, internet, atheros

I installed ubuntu 12.10 and my wireless card seem to have a lower performance compared to linux mint (any edition) - I mean it worked fine there.
For example it cannot connect to a router placed in a room next to mine (1 wall) and it could do it in mint or windows.
My wireless card is: 
02:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
Are there any known issues for this card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is the solution for the problem](http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=17833)

It's the old hwcrypt problem. In case you upgrade the kernel, and have no access to the web, don't blame network manager or wpasupplicant, create a file named

```
/etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
```

with the contents

```
options ath9k nohwcrypt=1
```

and reboot